# How does class generation with Apache CXF work?

Tags: java, cxf

So, I've created a client stub application with Apache CXF from a WSDL. The process was relatively straight-forward. I did it within SoapUI interface. I  supplied the WSDL location, told CXF to generate the client stub and hit okay.

Then, I imported the project into Eclipse, added the Apache CXF libraries, configured some security options, certs and whatnot. 
I wrote a main with a few test calls to my webservice, and... **it worked.**

Now my problem is that I don't know WHY it worked. To be more specific, when I hit run in Eclipse, the debug output clearly shows that there are CXF classes being invoked.

`INFO: Loaded configuration file cxf.xml.`
and 
`org.apache.cxf.service.factory.ReflectionServiceFactoryBean buildServiceFromWSDL`

In my `main()` I'm invoking the

```
MyServices ss = new MyServices(wsdlURL, SERVICE_NAME);
port = ss.getWSHttpBindingMyService();
```

But the `MyServices` class extends `javax.xml.ws.Service` and there's nothing that hints to CXF.

wsdl2java also generated a `MyService` interface and a `MyServiceImpl` class that sits in the same package. It looks like a good candidate. In my `main()` I can write stuff like `port.someMethod(someRequest)`. If I ctrl-click on `someMethod` and follow the implementation, it actually brings me to `MyServiceImpl` class but there's only dummy code there!

```
public Boolean someMethod(SomeRequest request) { 
            LOG.info("Executing operation");
            System.out.println(request);
            try {
                Boolean _return = null;
                return _return;
            } catch (java.lang.Exception ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
                throw new RuntimeException(ex);
            }
        }
```

So there must be some configuration somewhere that is telling the runtime which implementation to use. But I cannot figure out where or which one it is.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Whether you use cxf or wsdl2java to generate the client code .
The client code will be generated as per the J2EE specification.

The code generated is just the declaration of service , the implementation of service will be on server.

The client code make uses of the  webservice wsdl location to find the service and the operation exposed by it.

Check in your MyServices , You will see your service URL.
Ex

```
wsdlLocation = `"http://127.0.0.1/bookstore/services/search?wsdl"`
```

Thanks

Comment: Are you creating any client instance in your code . i.e org.apache.cxf.endpoint.Client client = org.apache.cxf.frontend.ClientProxy
                        .getClient(port);

Comment: This Client  instance which you are creating  comes from  cxf related jar. You have added cxf client jar dependencies in your project. So  once you try to run main program it tries  to read your local cxf.xml  configuration file to check for configurations. And  after that it executes the call.